# PM2 Managing PHP Script - Cluster mode

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, cluster-computing, pm2

Currently i'm successfully managing some PHP deamons (single instance) with PM2, and, so far so good!

With PM2 and while managing Node.js/IO.js apps, i can launch them in cluster mode on PM2 with no stress! The same does not happen with the mentioned php deamons!

So, first of all, is it even possible to manage/launch clustered instances of a PHP script using PM2 (or is that PM2 feature only usable on Node.js/IO.js scripts)?

If so (possible to do), what special "tuneups" are required to cluster the PHP scripts with PM2!?

While trying to launch some `pm2 start xxx.php -i 2 --name XXX`, i get the following error @ the error log path:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function._load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pmx/lib/transaction.js:62:21)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainer.js:200:23
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1209:30
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Utility.js:126:13)
    at WriteStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

... that makes me believe that it can't even parse the given PHP file!

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you can't use cluster mode with php.

The pm2 cluster mode only works with javascript. Internally it's using the nodejs [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module and *requiring* your script ([code line](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/blob/242f564f4c3297a9457bfcaf736297063612b7ee/lib/ProcessContainer.js)). 
This also explains your error, pm2 tries to execute the php code with javascript (hence the `SyntaxError`).

When using fork mode, it's using your interpreter (here php) to launch the script. This is why you can also run python or ruby on top of nodejs!

Comment: Is it possible to run multiple instances of a PHP script using PM2?

Comment: Yes you can! If the instance is a server you'd have to give it different listening ports though.

Comment: How would I do that? The PHP script is just something that needs to run on the server to perform some background tasks so no listening ports are required.

Comment: ok then I don't see the issue just run your script in fork mode ;). Why would you need multiple instance of your script and how are they talking together?

Comment: They are 'communicating' through an sql database. There's a table with a list of jobs that need to be performed. one script claims a job performs it and deletes the job if successful. I want to have multiple php scripts running so more work gets done in the same amount of time. I couldn't figure out how to run more instances of the same script in fork mode.